# Getting poor performance while saving to Redis cache (using ServiceStack.Redis)

Tags: caching, azure, redis, azure-caching, servicestack.redis

I am getting very poor performance while saving data to Redis cache.

Scenario :

1) Utilizing Redis cache service (provided by Microsoft Azure).
2) Running code in Virtual Machine created on Azure. 
3) Both VM and Cache service are created on same Location

Code Snippet:

```
    public void MyCustomFunction()
    {
        Stopwatch totalTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        RedisEndpoint config = new RedisEndpoint();
        config.Ssl = true;
        config.Host = "redis.redis.cache.windows.net";
        config.Password = Form1.Password;
        config.Port = 6380;
        RedisClient client = new RedisClient(config);

        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            var currentStopWatchTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var msgClient = client.As<Message>();

            List<string> dataToUpload = ClientData.GetRandomData();
            string myCachedItem_1 = dataToUpload[1].ToString();

            Random ran = new Random();
            string newKey = string.Empty;
            newKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            Message newItem = new Message
            {
                Id = msgClient.GetNextSequence(), // Size : Long variable
                //Id = (long)ran.Next(),
                Key = j.ToString(),             // Size: Int32 variable
                Value = newKey,                 // Size : Guid string variable
                Description = myCachedItem_1    // Size : 5 KB
            };

            string listName = ran.Next(1, 6).ToString();
            msgClient.Lists[listName].Add(newItem);
            //msgClient.Store(newItem);

            Console.WriteLine("Loop Count : " + j++ + " , Total no. of items in List : " + listName + " are : " + msgClient.Lists[listName].Count);

            Console.WriteLine("Current Time: " + currentStopWatchTime.ElapsedMilliseconds + " Total time:" + totalTime.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.WriteLine("Cache saved");
        }
    }
```

### Performance (While Saving):

**Note : (All times are in milliseconds)**

Loop Count : 0 , Total no. of items in List : 2 are : 1
Current Time: 310 Total time:342
Cache saved
Loop Count : 1 , Total no. of items in List : 3 are : 1
Current Time: 6 Total time:349
Cache saved
Loop Count : 2 , Total no. of items in List : 5 are : 1
Current Time: 3 Total time:353
Cache saved
Loop Count : 3 , Total no. of items in List : 5 are : 2
Current Time: 3 Total time:356
Cache saved
Loop Count : 4 , Total no. of items in List : 5 are : 3
Current Time: 3 Total time:360
Cache saved

.
.
.
.
.

Loop Count : 330 , Total no. of items in List : 4 are : 69
Current Time: 2 Total time:7057
Cache saved
Loop Count : 331 , Total no. of items in List : 4 are : 70
Current Time: 3 Total time:7061
Cache saved
Loop Count : 332 , Total no. of items in List : 4 are : 71
Current Time: 2 Total time:7064
Cache saved

### Performance (While Fetching)

List :  1
No. of items : 110
Time :  57

List :  2
No. of items : 90
Time :  45

List :  3
No. of items : 51
Time :  23

List :  4
No. of items : 75
Time :  32

List :  5
No. of items : 63
Time :  33

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? Size of Redis and pricing tier, same for the VM? Can you use connection pooling (PooledRedisClientManager)?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kefalidis, 

Redis Cache : Standard 1 GB
VM : Standard, A2(2 cores, 3.5 GB memory)

I am using Redis cache first time, and I am not much aware about PooledRedisClientManager. Can you give any great reference for it? If possible, I can do these operations on multiple threads.

Comment: Will turn off the SSL be different? Have a try to set SSL as false

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing in batches you should look at reducing the number of synchronous network requests that you're making to reduce your latency which is going to be the major performance issue when communicating with network services.

For this example you're making a read when you call:

```
msgClient.GetNextSequence();
```

and a write when you make:

```
msgClient.Lists[listName].Add(newItem);
```

Which is a total of 1000 synchronous request/reply network requests in a single thread where each operation is dependent and has to complete before the next one can be sent which is why network latency is going to be a major source of performance issues which you should look at optimizing.

#### Batching Requests

If you're dealing with batched requests this can be optimized greatly by reducing the number of reads and writes by fetching all ids in a single request and storing them using the `AddRange()` batch operation, e.g:

```
var redisMessages = Redis.As<Message>();
const int batchSize = 500;

//fetch next 500 sequence of ids in a single request
var nextIds = redisMessages.GetNextSequence(batchSize); 

var msgBatch = batchSize.Times(i => 
    new Message {
        Id = nextIds - (batchSize - i) + 1,
        Key = i.ToString(), 
        Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Description = "Description"
    });

//Store all messages in a single multi operation request
redisMessages.Lists[listName].AddRange(msgBatch);
```

This will condense the 1000 redis operations down to 2 operations.

Than if you need to you can fetch all messages with:

```
var allMsgs = redisMessages.Lists[listName].GetAll();
```

or specific ranges using `GetRange(startingFrom,endingAt)` API's.

Comment: Thanks @mythz for your inputs. Actually I can't do operations in batches (based on our scenario) but I can use multi-threading here. When I am trying to run this code on multiple threads, I am getting an exception that

  `The Read method cannot be called when another read operation is pending.`  

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KushalArora the `RedisClient` is a non-threadsafe instance and can't be re-used across threads, so you need to get a new RedisClient from the RedisManager in each thread.